# Why can the compiler not find documented function in ioctls crate?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the functions of the [ioctls](https://docs.rs/ioctls/0.6.1/ioctls/#functions) crate. I added it to the Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
ioctls = "0.6.1"
```

And I'm calling like this:

```
ioctls::spi_ioc_wr_max_speed_hz(fd, &speed);
```

but I get

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `spi_ioc_wr_max_speed_hz` in crate `ioctls`
   --> src/w25q.rs:127:17
    |
127 |         ioctls::spi_ioc_wr_max_speed_hz(fd, &speed);
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `ioctls`
```

The function exists and is pub: https://docs.rs/ioctls/0.6.1/ioctls/fn.spi_ioc_wr_max_speed_hz.html

Comment: Is your target os and architecture linux x86_64?

Comment: @kmdreko no, it's ARM on raspberry pi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you see on [docs.rs](https://docs.rs/ioctls/0.6.1/ioctls/) is built with a target toolchain and feature set in mind, usually the most common and/or extensive. And for most crates it doesn't matter, but for lower level utilities it can be misleading. You can change the target platform in the top bar (if generated by the crate author).

Many of the `ioctls` functions are only available for the x86_64 architecture. You can see the docs for the `i686` architecture [here](https://docs.rs/ioctls/0.6.1/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/ioctls/index.html#functions) to see more what you'd expect on `ARM`. I don't know enough about `ioctls` to advise a solution or workaround for this missing function.

In the future, if you'd like to see the exact docs to expect, generate and view them locally (with target architecture if not already set):

```
cargo doc --target armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --open
```